# Filtering POSIXct timestamps

Tags: r, dplyr, posixlt

I am trying to filter a df with about 50 entries by time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

rush_hour <- filter(travel_times$`Actual departure` >= as.POSIXct("% 07:00:00") & travel_times$`Actual departure` <= as.POSIXct("% 18:00:00"))
```

However, I mostly get 
*Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format*. Obviously I had other ones when trying to convert and whatnot. Have been through several packages although nothing worked so far.

Our timestamp is "%Y-%M-%D %H:%M%:S" but i lack the knowledge to actually filter them, according to my task.

I appreciate any help I can get. I am already quite sure it's gonna be a very simple mistake easily avoided with deeper knowledge of the whole process behind it..

Update:
Tried something like

```
filter(travel_times$`Actual departure` >= as.POSIXct("% 07:00:00", tz="UTC") & travel_times$`Actual departure` <= as.POSIXct("% 18:00:00"))
```

and i get the error : *Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format*.
Sadly I have no idea how to go about this. I never used this format before either.

Comment: `"% 07:00:00"` is not a valid format. If you are trying to filter by time alone (without considering the date), you can use `format` to extract time components and then to numeric, or you can use the `lubridate` package.

Comment: So I cant just filter for specific parts in the column? Good to know.  When formatting, does the Year, Month, Day still persist or is it gone? Although the date doesnt matter for the example, I dont want to delete them just like that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to filter for the specific time-period the task required.
I accomplished this by using :

```
hms <- format(as.POSIXct(travel_times$`Actual departure`), "%H:%M:%S")
hms

rush_hour <- travel_times[hms >= "07:00:00" & hms <= "18:00:00",]

off_peak <- travel_times[hms < "07:00:00" | hms > "18:00:00",]
```

Found this answer in another question posted on stackoverflow, cant find the page again though. Hope this helps everyone with a similar issue.